# How to get git branch of colleague who was fired

Tags: git, version-control, repository, branch, user-permissions

**The Short Question**

Given that I have read-only access to another git repo on the same server, how can I copy a specific branch from that repo into my own?

**The Long Story**

My colleague and I were writing code on the same dev server.

I am `user1` and my git repo resides here:

```
/home/user1/website
```

My colleague is `user2` and his git repo resides here:

```
/home/user2/website
```

He was working on a branch called `hotfix`.

**The Bad News**

He was fired before he could push his `hotfix` branch to our remote repo (hosted elsewhere).  Therefore, from my repo, I am unable to `git checkout` or `git fetch` his `hotfix`.

Furthermore, I only have read-only privileges within his directory.  If I `cd` to his repo at `/home/user2/website`, the current branch that is checked out is `master`.  If I try to `git checkout hotfix` from within his repo, I get this error message:

```
fatal: Unable to create '/home/user2/.git/index.lock': Permission denied
```

**The Good News**

I have read-only privileges.  Although I cannot `git checkout`, I can indeed `git show`, `git log`, `git diff`, etc.

**So My Question Is...**

Given that I have read-only access to my colleague's repo, how can I copy a specific branch from his repo to mine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of ways; here are two:

- Clone it:

  ```
  cd $HOME
  mkdir his
  cd his
  git clone /home/user2/website
  ```

  Now you have an entirely separate repository that's a clone of that repository.
- Add it as a remote, then fetch:

  ```
  git remote add his file:///home/user2/website
  git fetch his
  ```

  Now your repository has `remotes/his/` branches, which you can inspect, cherry-pick from, create local branches based-on, and so on.

The `git remote add` method works with networking protocols, so if you have access to the machine (say, via `ssh`) you can use that even if you're on your own computer (laptop, etc).

See the description in the [`git clone` documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) regarding caveats when using shared local files (with `--local`, `--no-hardlinks`, or `--shared`).